# How to make Assetic work with resources defined with Twig namespaces?

Tags: php, twig, silex, assetic

I'm trying to make simple task: process assetic blocks in twig templates with Silex. I just registered `TwigServiceProvider` and `AsseticServiceProvider`.

All my assetic blocks are recognized by twig parser but no assets that defined with namespace notation (like "@App/image.jpg") are added to the Asset Manager. And when Assetic tries to resolve my asset it generate all paths but can't load asset from Asset Manager.

My question: at what time assets are loaded into Assets Manager object? What need I do to make my app automatically dump and load all assets at time when twig templates are processed.

**index.php**:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider());

$app->register(new SilexAssetic\AsseticServiceProvider());

$app['assetic.path_to_web'] = __DIR__ . '/assets';
$app['assetic.options'] = array(
    'auto_dump_assets' => true,
    'debug' => true,
);

$app['twig.loader.filesystem']->addPath(__DIR__.'/views', 'App');

if ($app['assetic.options']['auto_dump_assets']){
    $dumper = $app['assetic.dumper'];
    if (isset($app['twig'])) {
        $dumper->addTwigAssets();
    }
    $dumper->dumpAssets();
}

$app->get('/', function(Silex\Application $app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('@App/index.html.twig');
});
```

**index.html.twig**:

```
{% image '@App/demo.jpg'  %}
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" class="img-responsive"  alt="">
{% endimage %}
```

The problem is in **@** sign. When I remove it, all working fine. But Assetic knows how to deal with namespaces. And I want it to work with namespaces because this templates will also be used by Symfony application where all is working fine now with **@** signs.